# Algebra Equation with equals on left hand side

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$6 = 4 - 2x =$

Show the answer with the mechanics of working out.

Comment: Presumably the exercise wants you to solve for $x$. But that is a guess, since quite non-standard (I am being excessively polite) notation is being used.

Comment: In the way you present this there is no meaning. Sometimes we "chain" equalities together, like $(x+y)^2=(x+y)(x+y)=x^2+2xy+y^2$, however, there's nothing after the second equality sign, so as this stands there's no meaning.

Answer (score 5):

**Equality**: "$=$" is a symmetric relation, as are all *[equivalence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Examples)*: $$a = b \quad \overbrace{\iff}^{\text{equivalent}}\quad b = a$$ That is, it doesn't matter if we replace $\;$ "$a$ is equal to $b$" $\;$ with $\;$ "$b$ is equal to $a$:" $\;$ both expressions tell us precisely the same thing.

So, the following two equations (left hand side & right hand side of the arrow) are *equivalent* (meaning, really, that they give the *same* identical information: 
$$6 = 4 - 2x \iff 4 - 2x = 6$$

---

Now, I am assuming that you need to solve for $x$. Let's just go ahead and use the form of the equation you were given:

- $(1)$ **add** $+ 2x$ to each side of the equation.$$\begin{align} 6 & = 4 - 2x \\ \\ 2x + 6 & = 4 - 2x + 2x\end{align}$$ Simplify.
- $(2)$ **Subtract** $6$ from each side of the equation. Simplify.
- $(3)$ **Divide** each side of the equation by $2$. (Put differently, you can **multiply** each side of the equation by $\frac 12).$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was trying to find the value of X. These explanations are very good. The equals being on the left hand side rather then on the right hand side was confusing me. But now I know that it is equal as explained by amWhy

Comment: Let me know what you obtain, following each step above: I "showed" you the first step, now simplify. The proceed with the other steps. I'll be happy to check your progress. I'm sure you can do it!

Comment: @amWhy: +1 for typing all of those details out! :-)

Comment: @amWhy Just saying, but some people who have started with algebra-precalculus may not understand what a relation is, let alone a symmetric relation. I think you should include a link which explains equivalence in classical logic as well as relations. Thanks :-)

Comment: You're right, @ΠάρτηΚοηλί: I'll include a link.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter left or right.

We can add $2x$ on both sides to get $$6+2x=4-2x+2x$$ $$\implies 6+2x=4$$ then subtract 6 on both sides we get $$6-6+2x=4-6$$ $$\implies 2x=-2$$ then divide 2 on both sides we get $$\frac{2}{2}x=\frac{-2}{2}$$ $$\implies x=-1.$$

If we have an equation, it is "legal" to perform addition, subtraction, multiplication and division (except by 0) by equal number on both sides. Later you will also learn that it is also "legal" to take the log, power, derivative and integral and so on, on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

**Given the equation:** 
$$\boxed{6=4-2x}$$
**We can subtract $-4$ from both sides:**
$$6-4=4-4-2x$$
**Simplifying we are left with:**
$$2=-2x$$
**Dividing by $-2$ on both sides to isolate x:**
$$\dfrac{2}{-2}=\dfrac{-2x}{-2}$$
**Leaving us with the solution:**
$$\boxed{x=-1}$$

**We can check we have the correct solution by plugging the $-1$ back into the original equation:**

$$6=4-2(-1)$$

$$6=4+2$$

$$\boxed{6=6}$$

**We find the answers are the same which proves we have the correct solution.**